# Redirect after facebook login not getting facebook user ID

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

So this is what I'm doing- I am using facebook login for my site using the php-sdk. I have given the redirect URI to a function that checks if the user exists in my database, if not create the user, then redirect to my home page.

```
redirect uri is http://somedomain.com/login/check_fb_login
check_fb_login will check if user exists in db, if not create
```

However, my check_fb_login is not getting the value of the userID.

```
 $facebook->getUser() is getting 0
```

Why is this so? getUser should return a value because the user has already been authenticated by facebook right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you are initializing $this->facebook object (by printing appId) or not.

And also See this links:

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790272/why-is-facebook-php-sdk-getuser-always-returning-0)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184199/facebook-getuser-returns-0)

[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417516/facebook-getuser-always-returns-0)

[link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226868/php-sdk-3-1-1-getuser-sometimes-return-0)

Answer (score 2):

it might be a bug, see http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/223499947703278

but also search for facebook->getUser() returns 0 on stackoverflow, there are a lot of topics about it so it could be something else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it by adding a full url.  So instead of

```
http://somedomain.com/login/check_fb_login
```

try

```
http://somedomain.com/login/check_fb_login/index.php
```

I also made sure that this was the same url in Site URL: and Mobile Site URL: on my Facebook Developers app page, and in the connection code:

```
$app_id     = "my_id";
$app_secret = "my_secret";
$site_url   = "http://somedomain.com/login/check_fb_login/index.php";
```